# Codimension inequality of prime ideal in a regular local ring

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, krull-dimension, local-rings

The following is an exercise (#6) of Eisenbud's commutative algebra, chapter 10:

**Exercise.** We mentioned that if $P$ is a prime ideal in a regular local ring $R$ and if $R\to S$ is a map of local rings, then $\operatorname{codim} PS\leq \operatorname{codim} P$. $(\cdots)$

I can't see where the author mentioned this before this exercise. How can we prove this?

Comment: This is a direct consequence of theorem 10.10.

Comment: @user782932 Then where the regularity condition should be used?

Comment: The conditions should be changed in 10.10. dim R should be codim P and S/mS should be S/PS. Using that $R_P$ is regular local (proved in chapter 19 in Eisenbud) then one follows the proof of 10.10.

Comment: @user782932 Thanks but I still can't see how to use that $R_P$ is regular local. There are only few theorems in chapter 10 of eisenbud about regular local rings.

Comment: I don't think the theorems in Chapter 10 are enough to prove this one(In fact, he just describes several basic properties of regular local rings in the last section of Chapter 10). Maybe that's why Eisenbud just states it in the exercise without proof. The argument I know depends on some deeper results.

Comment: @user782932 Can you introduce the argument you know?

Comment: On page 236 of Eisenbud's book, he mentioned that the proof can be found in Serre's book local algebra with a slightly stronger result.

Comment: @user782932 Thanks. It seems some technical tools are used. I should find for a simpler proof for this special case

Comment: The only proof I know uses Cohen factorization, which is a non-trivial result. I suggest you to ask the same question on MathOverflow, where there are specialists in homological conjectures. Maybe they know a simpler proof. If you don't get a satisfactory answer, then I can post a proof here.

Comment: @user26857 I asked the same question in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/420702/codimension-inequality-of-prime-ideal-in-a-regular-local-ring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can reduce the question to the case when $S$ is a local integral domain. Let $Q\subset S$ be a minimal prime over $PS$ such that $\mathrm{ht}(Q)=\mathrm{ht}(PS)$. Let $Q_0\subset Q$ be a minimal prime such that $\mathrm{ht}(Q/Q_0)=\mathrm{ht}(Q)$. Now we may replace $S$ by $S/Q_0$, which is an integral domain.

If $S$ is an integral domain and $R\to S$ is surjective, then we can write $S=R/P'$, with $P'\subset R$ a prime ideal, and we have $PS=(P+P')/P'$. Now use Serre's Intersection Theorem (Serre, *Local Algebra*, Theorem 3, page 110) and get $$\mathrm{ht}(PS)=\mathrm{ht}((P+P')/P')=\mathrm{ht}(P+P')-\mathrm{ht}(P')\le \mathrm{ht}(P).$$

Then we use the Cohen Factorization; see Theorem (1.1) from L.L. Avramov, H.-B. Foxby, and B. Herzog, *Structure of Local Homomorphisms*, Journal of Algebra, 164(1994), 124–145.

**Theorem (Cohen factorization).** Let $\tau:R\to S$ be a local morphism between noetherian local rings. Then there exists a complete local ring $R'$ and two local morphisms $\varphi:R\to R'$ and $\varphi':R'\to S$ such that
(i) $\tau=\varphi'\circ\varphi$ and $\varphi'$ is surjective;
(ii) $\varphi$ is flat and $R'/\mathfrak m_RR'$ is regular, where $m_R$ denotes the maximal ideal of $R$.

Since $R\to R'$ is (faithfully) flat, we have $\mathrm{ht}(PR')\le\mathrm{ht}(P)$. Let $Q\subset R'$ be a minimal prime over $PR'$ such that $\mathrm{ht}(Q)=\mathrm{ht}(PR')$. Since flat morphisms satisfy going-down, we have $Q\cap R=P$, and then $R_P\to R'_Q$ is a local morphism and $\dim R'_Q\le\dim R_P+\dim R'_Q/PR'_Q$. But $\dim R'_Q/PR'_Q=0$, so we get $\mathrm{ht}(Q)\le \mathrm{ht}(P)$.